# How to batch format files of unknown format using python?

Tags: python, database, filesystems

I have a lot of files that end with `.plx` , which contains numerical data.

I wanna create a script that:

1. Goes through all the files in all the sub-folders and automatically change the extension from `.plx` to `.txt`
2. Change the data type from `str` to `float64` (except for the first row)
3. Load the array using `numpy.loadtxt`

For a single file that I changed its extension manually it will look like this:

```
x1, y1 = np.loadtxt('crvcopie.txt', delimiter=' ', unpack=True, skiprows= 1, dtype=str)
x1= x1.astype(np.float64)
y1 = y1.astype(np.float64)
plt.plot(x1,y1)
```

I can't attach an example here, but I'm looking for general guidance on how to execute these tasks !

Copied sample:

```
"rdf_na"
0 4.7858086e-17
0.05 8.7815539e-17
0.1 1.6690106e-16
0.15 3.2625349e-16
0.2 6.5081648e-16
0.25 1.317591e-15
```

Comment: "`I'm looking for general guidance...`" This is not really a "general guidance" site; please read the [tour] and the [ask] page, and this [help/on-topic], to understand why this site is about getting _specific answers_ to _specific questions_.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do this for more than 1 file?

Comment: Is your question how to rename a file?

Comment: you know the extension is merely cosmetic from the point of view of apps, right? you can open and edit your fale no matter what its name (including extension). It is just the user interface of some O.S. that force certain filenames to only be open with certain programs.

Comment: "Copied sample" of what?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It worked fine. Now I am looking how to automate it for all the files in all the subfolders in a given master folder. Loading multiple txt files for plotting is relatively easy. it is the extension changing script that I don't know how to write.

Comment: you don't __need__ to change the extension, just open the files.

Comment: @ScottHunter an example of what an individual .plx file contains.

Comment: @jsbueno I did not know that. indeed it worked just fine !

Answer (score 1):

As @jsbueno it will work just fine if you write .plx.
So loading multiple files will be something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import os

myfiles = [myfile for myfile in os.listdir() if myfile.endswith(".plx")]

for myfile in myfiles:
    x, y = np.loadtxt(myfile, delimiter=' ', unpack=True, skiprows= 1, dtype=str)
```